# Why there is no interface for stack collection types in the Java standard library?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, interface

Queues typically order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner while stacks in a LIFO (last-in-first-out) manner.

In the Java standard library there is a specific interface called `Queue` modelling a queue and a bunch of classes implementing it.

Although there are classes implementing a stack, like `Stack` (which extends `Vector`), `ArrayDeque` (which, as stated in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), "is likely to be faster than `Stack` when used as a stack") and `LinkedList` (with its `push` and `pop` methods), there is no specific interface for stack collection types.

Why there is no interface for stack collection types in the Java standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of interfaces in java implies that each class implementing an interface declares it.

You can conceive many interfaces for many roles but you can't design, each time, an interface, or your code starts to be very verbose.

So choices have to be made. Designing a LIFO interface and having the LIFO classes declaring it wasn't, obviously, seen as so much important.

Answer (score 5):

See [`java.util.Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface API

Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the beginning of the deque.

Deque has push, pop and peek methods

Comment: I was more concerned about the preventing aspect than the allowing one. The Queue interface allows to prevent using a data structure other than in a FIFO mode; there is no interface for preventing the use of a data structure other than in a LIFO mode.